# How can we show that $(x_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be a contraction. Fix some $x_1$ in $\Bbb R^n$ and define the
sequence $(x_n)_n$  by  $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Show that $(x_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence.

Now, this is what I understand so far.
Through the Contraction Mapping Theorem, f has a unique fixed point. Let that be $x^*$.
We have that $d(f(x_n), x^*) = d(x_{n+1}, x^*)\leqslant\lambda d(x_n, x^*)\leqslant\lambda^2 d(x_{n-1},x^*)\leqslant\ldots\leqslant\lambda^nd(x_1,x^*)\,.$

We can fix $N$ after which $\lambda^Nd(x_{n-(N-1)},x^*)<\varepsilon$.
I am not sure on this last part. Is it right and how do we proceed after this?

Comment: Use the fact that $0<\lambda <1$ for a proper contraction. (If $\lambda = 1$ there need to be a fixed point -- for example, a translation of the plane)

Comment: If this is an exercise, I think you are not supposed to use the Contraction Mapping Theorem since the goal of the exercise seems to be to reprove it. Otherwise, it would be too easy: since $0\le\lambda<1,$ $d(x_{n+1},x^*)\le\lambda^nd(x_1,x^*)\to0$ and you are done.

Comment: But then he would be asked to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence, isn't it? And then of course use that $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard distance is Cauchy complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have proved that
$$
d(x_n,x^*)\leq \lambda^n d(x_1,x^*),
$$
with $0<\lambda<1$.

To proof the convergence you need to show that for $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $d(x_n,x^*)<\varepsilon$.

Consider any $\varepsilon>0$, since $0<\lambda<1$ there exists $n_0$ such that
$$
\lambda^{n_0}<\frac{\epsilon}{d(x_1,x^*)}
$$
(since $\{\lambda^n\}$ converges to 0).

So, therefore, if $n>n_0$ then $\lambda^n<\lambda^{n_0}$ and
$$
d(x_n,x^*)\leq \lambda^n d(x_1,x^*)<\lambda^{n_0}d(x_1,x^*)<\varepsilon,
$$
as desired.